# A single generic playbook yaml to pull any image based on extra-vars value

Tags: ansible

I want to create a generic ansible playbook yaml that will pull and run any image based on extra-vars parameter received. 
E.g. ansible-playbook my generic.yml --extra-vars "image=helloworld version=2.1"

In generic.yml, I have the following lines, I am only showing the lines that are pertinent to my problem.

```
vars: imageName=image
      imageVersion=version
      pullImage="{{ imageName }}:{{ imageVersion }}"
tasks:
  - docker
    name: helloworld
    image: "{{ pullImage }}"
```

When I run my playbook, it is erroring on the last line image: "{{ pullImage }}"
The error msg said it is expecting a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Is the formatting only a problem of your post (copy & paste & remove non-relevant noise) or is that actually the problem?

You can see this is no valid YAML by running it through any [YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=vars%3A%20imageName%3Dimage%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20imageVersion%3Dversion%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pullImage%3D%22%7B%7B%20imageName%20%7D%7D%3A%7B%7B%20imageVersion%20%7D%7D%22%0Atasks%3A%0A%20%20-%20docker%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20helloworld%0A%20%20%20%20image%3A%20%22%7B%7B%20pullImage%20%7D%7D%22&type=json).

Correct tasks notation would look like this:

```
tasks:
  - docker:
      name: helloworld
      image: "{{ pullImage }}"
```

Comment: Hi udondan, I agree. I would like to add as additional reference that there are some examples of how syntax should be in the appropriate documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html#examples